# Amazon S3 Request Signature does not match

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, curl

I am using the curl command to retrieve the list of files from a specific S3 location. I am referring this official documentation: [S3_API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html).

In the canonical query string if I am providing the value of `canonical_query_string = 'prefix=202302'` I am able to get the list of files inside that folder using curl command. But now I wanted to get the files from a specific folder inside this folder so I changed my canonical query string to the value of `canonical_query_string = 'prefix=202302/test'`. This is the only change I am doing in my whole bash script. Curl command is giving 403 forbidden message and the output says that, The signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I even changed / to %2F but it didn't work. It is working for all the YYYYMM formats, for example I am able to list files for 202301, 202302 etc. Adding params like &marker=test in prefix throws same error that signature don't matches.

Sample curl script below.

```
curl -X GET -v --proxy "proxy_url" "https://s3endpoint?${canonical_query_string} -H "Authorization: authorization_header" -H "content_type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded -H "x-amz-content-sha256: ${http request payload hash}" -H "x-amz-date: ${current_date_iso8601}"
```

Also say if for some reasons /test is causing an issue. How can I get a list of more than 1000 objects in S3. In my curl output i cannot see any continuation token.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't `"`s missing?

Comment: @JamesZ Yes in curl command there isn't any missing of ". Because the same command is yielding me the result for query_string='prefix=202304' but not for 202304/test. FYI I am using this query string to generate canonical request. I am generating signature from this request using openssl dgst -sha256 | sed 's/^.* //' Let me know if u need any more information